# Can Spark identify the directory of checkpoint automaticity?

Tags: apache-spark, checkpoint

I'm learning Spark recently, got confused about checkpoint.

I have learned that checkpoint can store RDD in a local or HDFS directory, and it will truncate the lineage of RDD. But how can I get the right checkpoint file in another driver program? Can Spark get the path automaticity?

For example, I checkpointed an RDD in the first driver program, and want to reuse it in the second driver program, but the second driver program didn't know the path of the checkpoint file, is it possible to reuse the checkpoint file?

I wrote a demo about checkpoint as bellow. I checkpoint the "sum" RDD, and collect it after.

```
val ds = spark.read.option("delimiter", ",").csv("/Users/lulijun/git/spark_study/src/main/resources/sparktest.csv")
  .toDF("dt", "org", "pay", "per", "ord", "origin")


val filtered = ds.filter($"dt" > "20171026")

val groupby = filtered.groupBy("dt")

val sum = groupby.agg(("ord", "sum"), ("pay", "max"))

sum.count()

sum.checkpoint()

sum.collect()
```

But I found in the Spark Job triggered by action "collect", RDD nerver read checkpoint. Is it because the "sum" RDD already exists in memory? I'm confused about the method "computeOrReadCheckpoint", when will it read checkpoint?

```
 /**
   * Compute an RDD partition or read it from a checkpoint if the RDD is checkpointing.
   */
  private[spark] def computeOrReadCheckpoint(split: Partition, context: TaskContext): Iterator[T] =
  {
    if (isCheckpointedAndMaterialized) {
      firstParent[T].iterator(split, context)
    } else {
      compute(split, context)
    }
  }
```

By the way, what's the main difference between RDD checkpoint and chekpointing in Spark Streaming?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Checkpointing in batch mode is used only to cut the lineage. It is not designed for sharing data between different applications. Checkpoint data is used when single RDD is in multiple actions. In other words it is not applicable in your scenario. To share data between application you should write it to reliable distributed storage.

Checkpointing in streaming is used to provide fault tolerance in case of application failure. Once application is restarted it can reuse checkpoints to restore data and / or metadata. Similarly to batch it is not designed for data sharing.

Comment: So if I wrote checkpoint to HDFS with serveral replication and want to share data betweeen applications, how can I get the checkpoint's directory?